# Replace with 3 conditions is failing - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to accomplish is:

- If cells in column F contain a number, then convert it to a percentage
- If cells in column F are empty and the corresponding cell in column G contain 0 then write in cell in column F "-"
- If cells in column F dont contain a number and the corresponding cell in column G contain a number higher than 0 then write in cell in column F "Action Required"

Column G is formatted as number.

However, with the given code, everything becomes "-". Where is the trick?

```
Sub Replace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dataLastRow As Long, cell As Range, MyRng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyTab")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    dataLastRow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyRng = ws.Range("F2:F" & dataLastRow)
    
    '   Loop through column F
    For Each cell In MyRng
    If cell = "" And cell.Offset(0, 1) = 0 Then
                cell = "-"
    ElseIf cell = "" And cell.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Then
                cell = "Action Required"
    ElseIf cell >= 0 Then
    With MyRng
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
     .Value = .Value
    End With
           Else
            End If
        Next cell
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Should your percentage branch be formatting cell not myrng?  Can you show some source data ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks weird: you get a list of data, you need to summarise those data and instead of putting the summary in another column, you decide to overwrite your data with your summary.

In case you change your mind, I've written this formula which creates the summary (not entirely correct, some small adaptations need to be done):

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F1),G1=0),"-",IF(ISNUMBER(F1),F1,"Action required"))
```

(Oh, in case you use the formula, don't forget modifying the cell format into percentage.)